# Battery Charging Operation

Tags: power-supply

I am connecting 3 cells in series having 12volt each. So that I can acheive 36Volt as a output voltage. If i am charging these cells in series connected manner, which cell first gets charged? or all cells are equally chargerd? If first cell gets first charged mean, there is no current flow for next two cells. Am i correct? Please explain the charging operations of series connected cells...

Comment: What type of battery? Charging in series is not recommended unless the batteries are of identical size, type, and age. When in series they all charge at the same time, but as there is at most C/5 amps of charging current, charging in series is slower than charging each battery separately in parallel where N C/5 amps can be used.

Comment: LiFePo4 Battery. The 3 cells are equal capacity, same size and same characteristics.

Comment: If all cells are equally charged mean, there is not necessary for Charge Equalization. Then what is the purpose of charge equalization?

Comment: @Dan I'm having trouble following your arguement about slower charging in series. In either case, each cell gets C/5 and in either case the same power is delivered to the cells. I think the only difference is the _total_ charging voltage.

Comment: What kind of cells produce 12 V!!?

Comment: Tillium cells, of course. But seriously, what kind of batteries are you charging? Some kinds can be charged in series no problem. Some kinds explode. You need to specify.

Comment: If the chemistry is LiFePo4, then each of the items you call 'cells' is actually a pack of 3 cells itself, and may have intermediate tap points between the cells for balanced fast charging.

Comment: @JoeHass I would like to retract that last sentence as it is simply false.

Answer (score 1):

A battery is a collection of cells. A cell has a voltage defined by the chemistry. For example, all alkaline cells have a voltage around 1.6V. I don't think there are any *cells* that produce 12V, as you say in your question. You mean *battery*.

The current is the same everywhere in a series circuit. [Charge is conserved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation), and unless you have some very high voltages, you can't get it to fly off the wires or suck it in from your surroundings. So if you have a series circuit, and you put some charge in, exactly that much must come out the other end. Where else would it go?

Consequently, if you charge batteries in series, they will each receive exactly the same charging current. If they are all *exactly* identical, and were all *exactly* as much discharged at the start, then they will all charge equally.

The issue is that real batteries aren't exactly identical. Some chemistries, like lead acid, can handle a small charging current even when fully charged: the charging current then just flows them harmlessly. Thus if one battery charges first, no big deal. It will pass current and the others will continue to charge.

Other chemistries, like lithium batteries, tend to explode if overcharged. Since it's difficult to guarantee that each of the batteries are exactly identical, it's hard to predict which will be done charging first, and since the current must be the same in each battery because they are in series, it's difficult to charge lithium batteries in series.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, cells connected in series must receive the same charging current. The problem is that the voltage across the different cells can vary. So, if you try to charge the cells quickly using a relatively high voltage you can overcharge and damage cells that have a higher voltage.

Charging cells in series is a tricky problem, and there are many people trying to develop solutions for battery monitoring and charge management.

Comment: Yes you are correct. In series manner, the same current flows to all cell. Still i am not clearing in charging of the cells and charge Equalization.All cells are equally gets charged. Is it correct?

Comment: Your assumption is only correct if the cells are **exactly** identical, which is very difficult to achieve in the real world. So in general the answer is no, the cells are not equally charged.

Comment: Fine. Your answer is "the current flows to all series connected cells and only differnce is voltage level at each cell varies, at the same time all cells are charged. But not equal". Am i correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you Joe Hass. Say for example, I am charging these 3 cells, the 1st cell gets 60% charged, 2nd cell gets 40% charged and 3rd Cell gets 20% charged. For this case, How to Equalize Charge in series connected cells? If for fast charging case, simply we have to increase the current ratings. But for Charge Equalization how it works?

Comment: For charge equalization, you need a way to divert the current around cells when they become fully charged in order to prevent them from being overcharged.